# Return object key from array value

Tags: javascript, object

I want to return the key of the object where it's `ContractID` value equals `10`. So in this example I want to return `0`.

```
{
    0 : {ContractID: 10, Name: "dog"}
    1 : {ContractID: 20, Name: "bar"}
    2 : {ContractID: 30, Name: "foo"}
}
```

I've tried using the `filter` method but it doesn't work how I'd have wanted.

```
var id = objname.filter(p => p.ContractID == 10);
```

This instead returns the array, not the key. How can I return the key?

Comment: `const keys = Object.keys(objname).filter(key => objname[key].ContractId === 10)`

Comment: I'm puzzled by it being an object instead of an array

Comment: this filter yeah returns a keys which is an array but with unique item. => get your item with index 0

Answer (score 2):

Use find on the `Object.keys()`

```js
let obj = {
    '0' : {ContractID: 10, Name: "dog"},
    '1' : {ContractID: 20, Name: "bar"},
    '2' : {ContractID: 30, Name: "foo"}
}

let res = Object.keys(obj).find(e => obj[e].ContractID === 10);
console.log(res);
```

However, your "object" looks more like it should be an array. Either create it directly correct as an array, or convert it to one first. Then use `findIndex()`

```js
let obj = {
    '0' : {ContractID: 10, Name: "dog"},
    '1' : {ContractID: 20, Name: "bar"},
    '2' : {ContractID: 30, Name: "foo"}
};

obj.length = Object.keys(obj).length;
let arr = Array.from(obj);
let key = arr.findIndex(e => e.ContractID === 10);
console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `for in` loop :

```js
var o = {
    0 : {ContractID: 10, Name: "dog"},
    1 : {ContractID: 20, Name: "bar"},
    2 : {ContractID: 30, Name: "foo"}
};

var k;
for(key in o){
  if(o[key].ContractID == 10){
    k = key;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(k);
```